# How to delete kubernetes dashboard ui pod using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I installed kubernetes dashboard ui , but the status is aways pending. Now I want to delete the pending pod . Query current pod:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd   0/1     Pending   0          8d
```

now I am trying to delete pod:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd" not found
```

how to delete kubernetes dashboard pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either specify the namespace with your kubectl delete command or set the namespace context before executing the command.

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=kube-system
kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've previously specified it, `kubectl` operations default to being performed against the `default` namespace. You don't have a Pod called `kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd` in the `default` namespace, but as you see in the `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces` output you do have it in the `kube-system` namespace.  So, instead, do:

```
kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd --namespace=kube-system
```

Comment: I execute `kubectl delete pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd --namespace=kube-system` .the output is:Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd" not found @Amit Kumar Gupta

Comment: what is current status of `kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system` ? May be the pod doesn't exist anymore.